# How to generate Diffie Hellman parameters in Python?

Tags: python, diffie-hellman

I need to generate a PEM encoded string in Python which contains DH parameters, something like the following:

```
openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 1024
```

With the difference I would like to get a string object instead of writing to disk.

How to accomplish this?

While digging I found the following code:

```
from OpenSSL._util import ffi as _ffi, lib as _lib

dh = _lib.DH_new()
_lib.DH_generate_parameters_ex(dh, 2048, 2, _ffi.NULL)
_lib.DHparams_print_fp(dhfile, dh)
with open('dh.pem', 'w') as dhfile:
    _lib.DHparams_print_fp(dhfile, dh)
```

But this code writes to disk and uses a different format than PEM.

Comment: If you don't supply the `-out` argument the result will be written to stdout. So you could use `subprocess` to capture the output. Is this good enough?

Comment: There must be a better way, I updated my question with a working code sample that does something similar to what I need.

Comment: I was going to suggest pyOpenSSL: http://www.pyopenssl.org/en/latest/index.html, but that package doesn't appear to support `dhparams`. This question is linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560717/m2crypto-diffie-hellman-parameters-as-pem (unfortunately no answer there either).

Answer (score 3):

So, I had the same struggle. And thanks to some help from irc `FreeNode/#cryptography-dev`, I managed to puzzle this together:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dh as _dh
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces import DHBackend
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import ParameterFormat

def generate_diffie_hellman(key_size):
    # "generator is often 2 or 5" / "generator must be 2 or 5.." (depending on where you read)
    DHBackend.generate_dh_parameters(backend, generator=2, key_size=key_size)
    dh_parameters = _dh.generate_parameters(generator=2, key_size=key_size, backend=backend)
    return dh_parameters.parameter_bytes(Encoding.PEM, ParameterFormat.PKCS3)

with open('dh1024.pem', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(generate_diffie_hellman(1024))
```

For reference, I managed to bodge this together via the following resources and steps below. And I'll save my thought process here because I'll most likely come back here in a year in the need of the same help..

The hunt begain with the help:

> Given a DHParameters object, call parameter_bytes() and write them to a file:
>   https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.dh.DHParameters.parameter_bytes

So, [DHParameters](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/3bab819c558ead888825e33f8df3f17707ff2c20/src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py#L119) is an abstract class, so I needed a instance some how as the first argument. Not sure what that instance would be.

So after a bit of back and fourth, i got another pointer:

> https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.dh.generate_parameters

So, [generate_parameters](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.dh.generate_parameters) requires a `generator`, `key_size` and a `backend`. Now, two of those are easy. The [DHBackend](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/interfaces/#cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces.DHBackend) however, took me back to the beginning as it's also an [abstract class](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/6d04e958abef078042c9a82ddbaa2d3c384db4fa/src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py#L335) in need of a instance. So I took a random, more popular function to make my searching a bit easy *(as this question oddly is very niche)*. The target became: [load_pem_x509_certificate](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/interfaces/#cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces.X509Backend), which is a function of the same [anonymous class structure](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/6d04e958abef078042c9a82ddbaa2d3c384db4fa/src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py#L276) that I was struggling with.. So if I can get this to work, the same logic should apply to the more un-searched/un-helped class [DHBackend](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/interfaces/#cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces.DHBackend).

Which after a few searches lead me to [this reference documentation](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/c7ba7be8fe67c099339fcbcd90012fc257308628/docs/x509/reference.rst#loading-certificates):

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_data, default_backend())
```

Where `default_backend` is the backend instance I needed. Which can be simplified by searching and finding [this snippet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/_modules/cryptography/hazmat/backends/):

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
```

Piping that `backend` to `DHBackend.generate_dh_parameters(backend, generator=2, key_size=key_size)` meant that we didn't need to instanciate `DHBackend` as the first instance will be the instance of `cryptography`'s own backend.

---

Now, I'll end on the note.. I have NO clue what all this does or implies.
And as the [documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh/) says:

## Danger!

> This is a “Hazardous Materials” module. You should ONLY use it if you’re 100% absolutely sure that you know what you’re doing because this module is full of land mines, dragons, and dinosaurs with laser guns.